# Find a replacement for JavaModelUtil.getResolvedTypeName

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've always used `JavaModelUtil.getResolvedTypeName(ifield.getTypeSignature(), itype)` in my plugincode. This is internal code of eclipse and I'm trying to replace this code with a "legal" variation. But I seem to be unable to find an alternative.

So what can I use instead of `JavaModelUtil` to get the qualified classname, if I have only the `IField` and the `IType` in which the `IField` exists.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can use `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType.resolveType(String)`.  This is what `getResolvedTypeName` uses internally.  You will have to do a bit more processing since `resolveType` expects a name and not a signature (in other words, you need to pass `MyType` instead of `QMyType;`.  If you look at the signature and implementation of the `resolveType` method you should be able to figure out how to use it.